# define per user custom scope for cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

How can I define custom scopes on a per user basis using cognito?

For example I have scope resource1.read, resource1.write

I want user A to have resource1.read and resource1.write while user B has resource1.read only.

This is just a high level example. We have tons of different resources and wants to allow customers to manage what resource each user has access to.

I havent found a way to associate scopes with each individual users but only at a per pool level.

Is there a way to achieve this using only cognito or cognito + some AWS manged service or do I have to implement another API to manage the scopes myself?

Comment: Hey @Steve, did you get to a solution?

Comment: @RenatoGama no. it doesnt seem like its possible w/ claims approach. We ended up using the custom attributes

Comment: Hey @Steve! Thanks for your answer. Maybe you could elaborate more as an answer so I can award you the bounty :)

Comment: @RenatoGama done. let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

we couldn't find a way to make scope work on per user basis so we ended up using the custom attributes instead.

if you have less than 25 scopes (cognito max limit) then you can use one attribute per scope. P.S. just be aware you can't rename/remove the attribute once its in place unless you delete the whole pool and start over again.

For example your attributes might look like:

```
custom:resource1.read : "true"
custom:resource1.write : "false"
custom:resource2.read : "true"
custom:resource2.write : "true"
```

the idea is simple. instead of having all the scopes defined inside the scopes array we define it in regular custom attributes. When the code checks for scopes just loop thru all fields and find the one with correct prefix.

Comment: This custom attributes will appear in ID Token, not in access token, so did you used ID token for authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own authorization service and call it with the Pre token generation Lambda trigger:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html

This only applies to the ID token though, just like Steve's answer.

> You can use this AWS Lambda trigger to customize an identity token before Amazon Cognito generates it. You can use this trigger to add new claims, update claims, or suppress claims in the identity token.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This could be done without a custom authorization service, just store the list of roles/scopes in a single custom attribute (up to 2048 characters), and in the trigger add the values to the claims field.